# How to construct objects from a vector of string and avoid copying?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Let assume `MyClass` has two member variables of type `std::vector` one holding struct of type `Data` and another one `StrData` (which contains string) member variables. I deleted the default and copy constructors to prevent the compiler from unnecessary copying:

```
struct Data {
    int x;
    float y;
    Data(int x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    Data() = delete;
    Data(const Data& other) = delete;
};


struct StrData {
std::string xstr;
    StrData(std::string x) : xstr(x){}
    StrData() = delete;
    StrData(const StrData& other) = delete;
};


class MyClass {
    std::vector<Data> m_vect_data;
    std::vector<StrData> m_vect_str_data;
public:
    MyClass(const std::vector<Data> &m_vect_data,
            const std::vector<StrData> &m_vect_str_data) : m_vect_data(
            m_vect_data), m_vect_str_data(m_vect_str_data) {}
};
```

Now I am trying to construct my class with the following initializer list:

```
MyClass s{{{1,2.0}, {2,4.0}}, {{"name"}}};
```

When compiling this code I get the complain that:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘StrData::StrData(const StrData&)’
```

Why does the compiler correct initialized the struct `Data` that
    only contain integral type (int and float) while can not intialize
    the second struct i.e. `StrData`, without the need of a copy-constructor?

Comment: Perhaps this is the first error the compiler encountered, and it aborted the attempt to compile the constructor at that point, without bothering to try to construct the remaining class members.

Comment: *I deleted the default and copy constructors to prevent the compiler from unnecessary copying* -- I don't quite understand this reasoning.  The compiler will not do "unnecessary copying" if it is a good compiler.  Looks like you may be invoking "premature optimization".

Comment: You have `const std::vector<StrData> &m_vect_str_data` and then `m_vect_str_data(m_vect_str_data`. How, other than copying, do you expect to get the data out of a `const` `vector`? You may be looking for an rvalue reference and move semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of copying, you can move.

Firstly, there is a problem that you're using the `vector(std::initializer_list<T>, const Allocator&);` constructor of the vector. Initializer lists can only be copied, so that is a no-go for non-copyable types.

One alternative approach, is to first declare the lists as arrays, create a range of move iterators, and use the iterator constructor instead:

```
Data datas[] = {
    {1,2.0},
    {2,4.0},
};
StrData strs[] = {
    {"name"},
};
MyClass s{
    {std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(datas)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(datas))},
    {std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(strs)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(strs))},
};
```

Now, this doesn't work yet, since your constructor copies from the argument vectors. Simple solution is to take the vectors by value, and move them into the members:

```
MyClass(std::vector<Data> m_vect_data,
        std::vector<StrData> m_vect_str_data
       ) : m_vect_data(std::move(m_vect_data)),
           m_vect_str_data(std::move(m_vect_str_data))
       {}
```

Finally, you must make your `Data` and `StrData` classes movable (which they aren't implicitly because of the deleted copy constructor) or else the move iterator trick won't work:

```
struct Data {
    // ...
    Data(Data&&);
};
struct StrData {
    // ...
    StrData(StrData&&);
};
```

---

PS.

Making the classes non-copyable is only sensible as a debugging tool to find accidental copies. Especially in the case of `Data` which is just as fast to copy as it is to move.

Also, accepting vectors in the constructor is quite limiting. If it is possible for you to use templates, you could instead use a template constructor taking pairs of iterators instead.